# Microsoft Excel Column Search and Return

Tags: database, excel, organization

Lets say i have 2 sheets one containing:
Data for some info on products for emails,

```
p159    Ben54@ya
g456    Jo32@gm
k455    Jack45@ro
t888    Sally12@k
```

And a second sheet containing the code and the name the email has with it,

```
k455    Jackson
p159    Benjamin
g456    Joseph
```

Keep in mind there is alot more information and it is all scrambled about but organized into columns. Also some codes have an email but no name.

Now i need to combine in a sheet or column these Emails with the names given by finding the code from sheet one and sheet 2 and taking the info from that row and spitting it into a cell in a fashion such as

```
Jack45@ro:Jackson
```

So in the other row in no particular order (organization in the column of the emails:name isn't important)
it should look like so

```
Jack45@ro:Jackson
Jo32@gm:Joseph
Ben54@ya:Benjamin
```

Notice that Sally was omitted because she doesn't have a name to her email(I would rather ignore her info & its alright if that row gives #VALUE errors)

I have experimented but i keep getting errors #VALUE ?NAME #N/A Because i am grabbing fx from others and am having trouble formatting it properly.

TL:DR I need to search a column for a code then combine the data in the cell next to it with the cell next to the code in the other sheet.(I don't know if i typed that properly ;/)

So if anybody could make a function for this it would be greatly appreciated :)

Solution thanks to glh! Also from his function in my case I had to change the false's to true to fix some #N/A error.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)),"",B1&VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

I used

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,TRUE)),"",B1&":"&VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,TRUE))
```

Helpful tip...

If the data you are drawing from is derived from another function and when you select it you don't see the text you do in the cell, copy and paste the section and when you paste it select the paste with values and number formatting option from the small clipboard that pops up

Comment: I have tried things like this =ADDRESS(,MATCH(D:D,'01'!B:B,0),,,) and =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)) Because i found them on other sites but they do not work properly  Talk to me about java any day but excel functions i do not get :/

Comment: You might be interested in the VLOOKUP command.

Comment: Okay excel opened im making it now

Comment: =VLOOKUP(D1,'01'!C:C,'01'!C:C) I am getting #NUM errors?

Comment: nothing was it was i typo i think i will add the working line into the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data;

[image]

If you use:

- Excel 2007 +: `=IFERROR(B1&VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"")` in cell C1 in Sheet 1.
- Excel 2003-, `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)),"",B1&VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))`

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am getting a #NAME? and my data is identical to yours just seeing pnuts comment and yes a new sheet would be nice but not required

Comment: Good points. The question is a little vague, although it's got a lot of detail. If nothing else this should help understand. ;)

Comment: I copied direct. is your data in 1 or 2 columns? also if you have an earlier version of excel the `iferror` won't work.

Comment: I would be happy to help verify any vagueness in my question! I do have excel 2003 :( what command did iferror replace?

Comment: Thank you very much glh does the if just hide the errors, because i was messing with your first one and removed the iferror and tried =B1& ":" &VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE) and in my eyes its simple but its probably very sloppy as it causes #NA for the other cells but yours works great thankyou!

Comment: nothing wrong with errors if there handled correctly, just don't send an error to your CEO ;)

Comment: I am having an issue, instead of having the actual text in column one i have a function to the data that splits it from other data =LEFT(G32,SEARCH(" ", G32, 1))

Comment: I figured it out i need to press F9 to replace the formula result with the calculated result.